# What does 'bash -c' do?

Tags: linux, bash

I followed the following tutorial: http://davidtsadler.com/archives/2012/06/03/how-to-install-magento-on-ubuntu/

At some point it told me to execute the following command:

```
sudo bash -c "cat >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/magento-store.com <<EOF
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName  localhost.magento-store.com
  ServerAlias www.localhost.magento-store.com

  DocumentRoot /home/dev/public_html/magento-store.com/public

  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/dev/public_html/magento-store.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/dev/public_html/magento-store.com/log/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
EOF"
```

What did this command do, and how I can cancel that?

I restarted the computer, and it seems that it is still running. I looked in `.bashrc` and `.profile`, but I did not find it inside.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Invoking-Bash

Comment: The command should have run and completed instantaneously. To undo it, you need to edit the `magento-store.com` file.

Comment: http://davidtsadler.com/archives/2012/06/03/how-to-install-magento-on-ubuntu/ seems to be broken. Neither `davidtsadler.com` nor `www.davidtsadler.com` seems to be in DNS.

Comment: The linked page as it was when this question was asked https://web.archive.org/web/20131128063029/https://davidtsadler.com/archives/2012/06/03/how-to-install-magento-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Quoting from `man bash`:

> -c string If the -c option is present,  then  commands  are  read
> from string.
> If  there  are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

The command quoted by you would *append* the text in heredoc (i.e. the text in `VirtualHost` tag) to the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/magento-store.com`.

Comment: How is that different to without `-c` ?

Comment: @tjt263 practically speaking, not using -c in such cases will give you hours of debugging trying to escape various quotation marks in various ways and things still not working.

Comment: Also be aware that commands called from ```bash -c``` will be forced to singlethreading. eg: ```"bash -c 'ffmpeg -threads 4 -i input.mov output.mp4'"``` will call ffmpeg but it can only use one core even though you specified the "threads" parameter

Comment: @Christian why? that seems very unreasonable.

Comment: @user60561 Bash -c is forcing it to single-thread the string command, so calling for more threads results in a command that can only "see" 1 thread, thus only use that one

Comment: @Christian This behavior is not documented, and it also doesn't match actual behavior: https://i.imgur.com/ZeFAkDf.png

Comment: @user60561 To be fair, from you screenshot, it seems that it's `zsh`, not `bash`, that is actually running the script.

Comment: @NándorElődFekete No clue why that is, it happened the same when I just tried it now. However, when I run it from bash, the exact same results occur: https://i.imgur.com/zqZQVPU.png. Oddly enough, it looks like ffmpeg completely ignores the `-threads 4` argument.

Comment: @user60561 That's great. It would be very strange if `bash` would somehow restrict a child process' ability to use more CPUs than one. Thanks for retesting.

Comment: @voices without `-c` only shell scripts can be executed(e.g. `bash script.sh`), binary files(e.g. `/usr/bin/cat`, `/usr/bin/ls`) cannot be executed in that case, so the command specified in the question without `-c` will not work.

A little bit more about this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/710669/502177

Answer (score 19):

[The manual page for Bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) (e.g. `man bash`) says that the `-c` option executes the commands from a string; i.e. everything inside the quotes.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the man pages, either on your machine or on the Internet, like [this one](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Quote:

```
-c string
     If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string.
     If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional
     parameters, starting with $0.
```

Comment: "starting with $0" the subtlety that needed to be emphasized.