# mysqldump in Jenkinsfile can't connect to server

Tags: mysql, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

This is the stage in Jenkinsfile where the problem comes from :

```
stage ('Build & Run container') {
    imageMysql     = docker.build('backend-server-mysql-dev', '--no-cache -f build/docker/mysql/Dockerfile .')
    containerMysql = imageMysql.run("--name backend-server-mysql-dev -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e  MYSQL_ROOT_USER=root -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=mahmoud -e MYSQL_DATABASE=soextremedb")
    sh 'docker ps | docker exec -it backend-server-mysql-dev /bin/bash | ls -l | mysqldump -u root -proot soextremedb < soextremedb.sql'
}
```

This is the error message:

```
Shell Script -- docker ps | docker exec -it backend-server-mysql-dev /bin/bash | ls -l | mysqldump -u root -proot soextremedb < soextremedb.sql -- (self time 566ms)
[soextremeBackEnd_Dev-MBC6SQWYSNVE6ADN2QOAOGZ4YYVT5E6K7Y2FUP6ROOROWRMCPFOA] Running shell script
+ docker ps
+ docker exec -it backend-server-mysql-dev /bin/bash
+ ls -l
+ mysqldump -u root -proot soextremedb
**mysqldump: Got error: 2002: "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")" when trying to connect the input device is not a TTY**
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of issues with the `sh` command.

First, `|` is used to send the output of one command on to the next command, but it looks like you're just trying to execute a sequence of commands. For that, you can use `;` or `&&`. You might take a look at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159514/121121) for a great summary of shell operators.

Then, for your `docker exec` command, I think you actually want to call a series of commands non-interactively: leave off off the `-it` and use `/bin/bash -c` to pass a [command string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20858414/4121744) to the shell.

This will give you something like:

```
sh 'docker ps ; docker exec backend-server-mysql-dev /bin/bash -c "ls -l ; mysqldump -u root -proot soextremedb < soextremedb.sql"'
```

Comment: Thanks @bto

It worked. Now the next error says that :

/bin/bash: soextremedb.sql: No such file or directory

Comment: I'm glad that worked! Your next problem is _much_ different from this one; I'd actually suggest asking a new question to address it. Include the same `Jenkinsfile` code block, but also include the content of your `build/docker/mysql/Dockerfile` - there might be a problem with the `Dockerfile`, or a solution that would update the `Dockerfile`.