# Bash command usage meaning

Tags: bash, command

When I execute commands like this:

```
bash -c 'command1; command2; command3'
```

what does it mean? And in particular, what does "-c" mean?

Comment: You can find help on Linux commands using `man` tool and *"man-pages"*. E.g. `man bash`

Answer (score 0):

This question was already answered here:
[What does 'bash -c' do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858381/what-does-bash-c-do)

man bash:

```
-c string If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string.
If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional 
parameters, starting with $0.
```

Answer (score 0):

From `man bash` :

> If  the  -c  option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string. If there are arguments after the command_string, the first argument is assigned to $0 and  any  remaining arguments  are  assigned  to the positional parameters.  The assignment to $0 sets the name of the shell,which is used in warning and error messages.