# Why does terminal stop after run "bash" in a .bat file (WSL) and how to run it properly?

Tags: bash, batch-file, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I would like to automatize a process running a .bat file but using the bash terminal in my WSL2. These are my commands in my .bat:

```
bash
cd ~/Dev/Folder
nvm use 14.15.0
npm start
```

But the .bat stops after running "bash". I also tried with `bash && cd ~/Dev/Folder && nvm use 14.15.0 && npm start` and also replacing "bash" with "wsl", but same result.

[image: Image of the result]

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, so I would appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 4):

`bash` starts a new Bash shell and waits for it to exit, like for any other terminal command. The subsequent commands are *not* redirected to Bash - they'll be executed once the Bash process exits.

To run commands *within* Bash, [use the `-c` flag](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/a-guide-to-invoking-wsl/):

```
bash -c "cd ~/Dev/Folder && ls && nvm use 14.15.0 && npm start"
```

Also see [What does 'bash -c' do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858381/what-does-bash-c-do).

Comment: Almost worked. It goes to the directory and shows the files with ls, but it says `/bin/bash: nvm: command not found` when it gets there, same with npm when I remove nvm.

Comment: It may have to do with the `PATH` environment variable. You should make sure that the path that contains `nvm` and `npm` is in `PATH`. Or just invoke them using their full paths, like `/full/path/to/npm start`.