# executing shell command in docker composer gives me error

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to execute shell command in docker-compose.yml. Code is:

```yaml
    command: bash -c mkdir /opt/wa/usr/install_templates
```

When I do:

```sh
    sudo docker-compose up  serviceA
```

it gives me :

```
    serviceA     | mkdir: missing operand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `bash -c`, it runs the first string after the `-c` flag. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20858414/4676641) for more information. Docker is reading your command `bash -c mkdir /path/` and your bash command is just running `mkdir` in a bash subshell, causing that error.

You don't need to put `bash -c` before your commands in a docker-compose file. The Docker engine will handle running it in a shell for you and you can simply write the command you want to be run. I'd suggest replacing your command with this:

```yaml
command: mkdir /opt/wa/usr/install_templates
```

Alternatively, you could try putting the entire command into a string if you want to force the command to be run in bash:

```yaml
command: bash -c "mkdir /opt/wa/usr/install_templates"
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying now to do these comand: command: cp -r /sdfs/dsfs /dsfs/sfds and it seems don't do anything. :-(