exited with code 0 while running use docker-compose.yml
I am running PHP Apache server using Docker. This is my docker-compose.yml file content :
version: '3'

services: 
  php:
    image: php:8.2-cli
    ports:
      - '3000:80'
    volumes:
      - /Users/mac/Developer/laminas-sample-project:/var/www/html
      - /Users/mac/Developer/laminas-sample-project/scripts:/scripts
    #command: /bin/sh -c "chmod +x /scripts/entrypoint.sh" && "scripts/entrypoint.sh" && tail -f /dev/null
    command: /bin/bash -c "apt-get update" && "apache2-foreground" && tail -f /dev/null

Getting error like below :
laminas-sample-project-php-1  | Reading package lists...
laminas-sample-project-php-1 exited with code 0

I checked all existing answer but didn't help. Not getting whats is wrong happening.

You need to pass the entire command as one string to ‘bash -c’ everything after the first argument is passed to the program being executed.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20858414/14707109

As @kthompso indicates in their comment, the most direct answer is to make sure the entire command you're trying to run is inside the double-quoted string.
command: /bin/bash -c "apt-get update && apache2-foreground && tail -f /dev/null"

Command doesn't run a shell to process command:, but it does do a naïve word splitting.  Converting your original command to YAML syntax, it would look like
command:
  - /bin/bash
  - -c
  - apt-get update
  - &&
  - apache2-foreground
  - ...

sh -c only accepts a single command string; any further parameters set the positional variables in that string.  So your command: runs apt-get update, and when sh processes that string the variable $0 is set to &&, $1 to apache2-foreground, and so on.
This could be simplified significantly:

You should never need tail to "keep the container alive".  In this setup apache2-foreground runs as a foreground process and it will do that on its own.  You can remove the final tail command.
apt-get update only downloads package indexes but doesn't actually modify anything that's installed.  There's no reason to run it in isolation.  Actually doing an upgrade takes a lot of time and you wouldn't want to repeat it on every startup.  You can remove this too.
In many cases you can use /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash.  This gets around problems like GNU Bash not being present on Alpine images.  You need to make sure you're using the standard set of shell constructs (., not source) and avoid extended features like array-type variables.  What you're showing doesn't use any of this.
If you remove both of these, you're now running a simple command apache2-foreground and you can remove the sh -c wrapper.
But if you're trying to run a PHP script served by Apache, there's a dedicated php:apache setup for that.

That is, you might be able to write
version: '3.8' # most recent 3.x file version
services: 
  php:
    image: php:8.2-apache # <-- note changed image
    ports:
      - '3000:80'
    volumes:
      - /Users/mac/Developer/laminas-sample-project:/var/www/html
      - /Users/mac/Developer/laminas-sample-project/scripts:/scripts

with no command: at all.  I'd also consider using a Dockerfile to avoid the volumes: mounts and make this setup independent of what might be on the host system.
